# Interesting Power Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

The series is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} r(n)x^n$ , where $r(n)$ is defined as the divisor function. The question is , what is the radius of convergence of the power series?
Maybe it is not that interesting , but I am stuck with this one since we haven't had this function in our entire lecture and it came up in the latest worksheet.

Comment: Take a look at the growth rate of $r(n)$: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#Approximate_growth_rate

Comment: Crude estimates will do it. For $n\gt 1$ we have $2\le r(n)\le n$. Now comparison with $\sum_n nx^n$ shows the radius of convergence is $1$. (The function  called $r(n)$ in the OP is more commonly called $d(n)$ or $\tau(n)$.)

Answer (score 4):

Let $r(n)$ denote the *number* of divisors of $n$, or the *sum* of divisors of $n$, or more generally for some fixed $k$
$$r(n)=\sum_{d\mid n} d^k.$$
Then $1\le r(n)\le n^{k+1}$, so that (using $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]n=1$)
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{r(n)}=1 $$
and  the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty r(n)x^n$ is $1$.

Comment: So what can be said about the boundaries 1 and -1 ? 1 is self explanatory I guess.

Comment: Oh  right, same criteria , since lim sup of the root of the function is equal to 1 again if we insert the function, -1 should also be outside the interval.

Comment: We have divergence at endpoints, for there the terms do not even have limit $0$.